# Software Updates from terminal without sudo

Tags: apt, software-updater

Software Updates is capable of checking for updates and installing them without asking for a password except for kernel updates.

The same is not true for apt-get in a terminal. If you try to `apt-get update` without sudo you get an error: `Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)`.

Is there a command you could run in terminal which permits updating without using sudo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Software Updates uses `aptdaemon` to do all the work. You can do that from the command line using `aptdcon`:

Check for updates:

```
aptdcon --refresh
```

Install updates:

```
aptdcon --safe-upgrade
```

Comment: No longer available in my disco donkey repos

Comment: @RayFoss Ubuntu 19.04 reached end-of-live on 2020-01-23. On supported Ubuntu versions aptdaemon is still available

Comment: Today years old when I learned about this.

Answer (score 1):

open your sudoers file as `sudo nano /etc/sudoers` from your terminal and

Then do as

```
<your-username> ALL=NOPASSWD: sudo apt-get update
```

save & close.

Then check & If its asking same restart your PC and try again.

hope that helps.